# Dynamic lookup function for extracting the sheet name in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference, excel-2010

in excel, customer ids are present in different tab based on the zone/region and sheet are named as per zone/region. In one tab all the customer ids are listed. Need a dynamic function for extracting zone/region

Answer
Id Zone
1 East
2 West
3 South
4 
5

Sheet (East)
Id Customer Name
1   A

Sheet (West)
Id Customer Name
2   B

Sheet (South)
Id Customer Name
3   C

and in future any other sheet is added and customer id are present in those sheet then those sheet name based on the customer id

Comment: index() with match() but you should provide some clear examples

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're after. Maybe using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to paste your sample data as a table will help us understand better. 
Please explain the logic for retrieving the Zone.

Comment: Yes it is bit unclear. Also I think for future addition of new worksheets, you might need to `Excel Macro 4.0` --> `GET.CELL()` to capture the worksheet name or if you are in `MS365` it may not required not sure, still i have some doubt.